# JAVA imports not working after loading corresponding jar files (VLCJ)

Tags: java, vlcj

The following import is not working:

```
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.factory.MediaPlayerFactory;
```

(Neither any of the other uk.* imports)

I have loaded the JNA and JAR files, (as stated [here](http://capricasoftware.co.uk/projects/vlcj-4/tutorials/installation)) but i still get `"package uk.co... does not exist"`

To add the jar and jna, i've done **tools -> libraries -> new -> Add JAR/Folder**

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: *"I have loaded the JNA and JAR files"* - What precisely have you done?  What do you mean by "loaded"?

Comment: I am sorry for the lack of that information. I've added it to the question.

Comment: @Souza I guess you're talking about Eclipse. AFAIR, this creates a library. You need to add that new library to your build path. Or not create a library at all, and add the jar files to the build path directly.